# Spring Integration DSL | Jch Exception | Disconnecting from <<Server>> port 22

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I am trying to upload a file to remote SFTP server. I created the outbound flow from the same

```
@Configuration
public class SftpIntegrationFlow {
@Value("${report-uploader.reportingServer.remoteDirectory}")
private String remoteDirectory;

@Value("${report-uploader.reportingServer.fileEncoding}")
private String fileEncoding;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("cachedSftpSessionFactory")
private CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry> cachedSftpSessionFactory;

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sftpOutboundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("toSftpChannel")
            .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(this.cachedSftpSessionFactory, FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
                    .charset(Charset.forName(fileEncoding)).remoteFileSeparator("/")
                    .remoteDirectory(remoteDirectory).fileNameExpression("headers.get('FILE_NAME')")
                    .autoCreateDirectory(true).useTemporaryFileName(true).temporaryFileSuffix(".tranferring"))
            .get();
}

@Bean(name = "toSftpChannel")
public MessageChannel getMessageChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
}
```

My cachedSessionFactory looks like::

```
@Configuration
public class UploaderSftpConnectionFactoryBuilder {

@Value("${report-uploader.sftp-factory.host}")
private String host = null;
@Value("${report-uploader.sftp-factory.port}")
private Integer port = null;
@Value("classpath:${report-uploader.sftp-factory.privateKey}")
private Resource privateKey = null;
@Value("${report-uploader.sftp-factory.privateKeyPassphrase}")
private String privateKeyPassphrase = null;
@Value("${report-uploader.sftp-factory.user}")
private String user = null;
@Value("${report-uploader.sftp-factory.poolSize}")
private Integer poolSize = null;
@Value("${report-uploader.sftp-factory.sessionWaitTimeout}")
private Long sessionWaitTimeout = null;

private DefaultSftpSessionFactory getSftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory defaultSftpSessionFactory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();

    Optional.ofNullable(this.getHost()).ifPresent(value -> defaultSftpSessionFactory.setHost(value));
    Optional.ofNullable(this.getPort()).ifPresent(value -> defaultSftpSessionFactory.setPort(port));
    Optional.ofNullable(this.getPrivateKey()).ifPresent(
            value -> defaultSftpSessionFactory.setPrivateKey(privateKey));
    Optional.ofNullable(this.getPrivateKeyPassphrase()).ifPresent(
            value -> defaultSftpSessionFactory.setPrivateKeyPassphrase(value));
    Optional.ofNullable(this.getUser()).ifPresent(value -> defaultSftpSessionFactory.setUser(value));

    return defaultSftpSessionFactory;
}

@Bean(name = "cachedSftpSessionFactory")
public CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry> getCachedSftpSessionFactory() {
    CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry> cachedFtpSessionFactory = new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(
            getSftpSessionFactory());
    cachedFtpSessionFactory.setPoolSize(poolSize);
    cachedFtpSessionFactory.setSessionWaitTimeout(sessionWaitTimeout);
    return cachedFtpSessionFactory;
}

public String getHost() {
    return host;
}

public void setHost(String host) {
    this.host = host;
}

public Resource getPrivateKey() {
    return privateKey;
}

public void setPrivateKey(Resource privateKey) {
    this.privateKey = privateKey;
}

public String getPrivateKeyPassphrase() {
    return privateKeyPassphrase;
}

public void setPrivateKeyPassphrase(String privateKeyPassphrase) {
    this.privateKeyPassphrase = privateKeyPassphrase;
}

public Integer getPort() {
    return port;
}

public void setPort(Integer port) {
    this.port = port;
}

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}
}
```

And the service the initiates the uploading::

```
@Service
public class SftpFileUploaderServiceImpl implements SftpFileUploaderService     {
@Value("${report-uploader.reportingServer.remoteDirectory}")
private String remoteDirectory;

@Value("${report-uploader.reportingServer.attemptsInCaseOfFaliure}")
private Integer noOfAttempts = 5;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("toSftpChannel")
private MessageChannel toSftpChannel;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("CachedSftpSessionFactory")
private CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry> CachedSftpSessionFactory;

public static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SftpFileUploaderServiceImpl.class);

@Override
public boolean uploadFileToSftpServer(String filename, String fileContent) {
    LOG.debug("Uploading file '{}' to the sftp server. File content: {}", filename, fileContent);
    int i = 0;
    // Try to upload file to the SFTP server retry for the configurable
    // number of times in case of failure
    while (i < noOfAttempts) {
        if (i > 0) {
            LOG.info("Retrying to uploade file '{}' to the sftp server....Attempt {}.", filename, i + 1);
        }
        try {
            i++;
            return this.toSftpChannel
                    .send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(fileContent).setHeader("FILE_NAME", filename).build());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (i >= noOfAttempts) {
                LOG.error("Exception occured while sending file:'{}' to the SFTP server.", filename);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
    LOG.info("Could not upload file Uploading file '{}' to the sftp server in {} attempts. Aborting!!", filename,
            noOfAttempts);
    return false;
}

private RemoteFileTemplate<LsEntry> getRemoteTemplate() {
    return new RemoteFileTemplate<>(this.cachedSftpSessionFactory);
}
}
```

When the service is called, debug logs shows the below trace::

```
2016-04-27 11:01:12.034  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1]     c.s.l.s.rest.FileUploaderResource        : Received request to manually initiate report uploading between 2016-04-26T00:00:00Z & 2016-04-27T00:00:00Z.
2016-04-27 11:01:13.337 DEBUG 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1]  c.s.l.s.s.impl.FileUploaderHandlerImpl   : Processing the request for report between 2016-04-26T00:00:00Z & 2016-04-27T00:00:00Z
2016-04-27 11:01:13.339 DEBUG 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1]     c.s.l.s.s.impl.FileUploaderHandlerImpl   : The reportting file 'Test_2016-04-27_2016-04-26_Test.tsv' will be created with the below content::
*************Start*****************
This is only test content.
************End********************
2016-04-27 11:01:13.339  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] c.s.l.s.s.impl.FileUploaderHandlerImpl   : Initializing the file uploading process......
2016-04-27 11:01:13.340 DEBUG 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1]  c.s.l.s.s.impl.FileUploaderHandlerImpl   : Uploading tempFile:'Test_2016-04-27_2016-04-26_Test.tsv.tmp' to server.
2016-04-27 11:01:33.125 DEBUG 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] c.s.l.s.s.i.SftpFileUploaderServiceImpl  : Uploading file 'Test_2016-04-27_2016-04-26_Test.tsv.tmp' to the sftp server. File content: 1
2016-04-27 11:01:33.893  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Connecting to <<Server_IP>> port 22
2016-04-27 11:01:33.895  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Connection established
2016-04-27 11:01:33.910  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4
2016-04-27 11:01:33.910  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.52
2016-04-27 11:01:33.910  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
2016-04-27 11:01:33.911  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : aes256-ctr is not available.
2016-04-27 11:01:33.912  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : aes192-ctr is not available.
2016-04-27 11:01:33.912  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : aes256-cbc is not available.
2016-04-27 11:01:33.912  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : aes192-cbc is not available.
2016-04-27 11:01:33.912  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
2016-04-27 11:01:33.934  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
2016-04-27 11:01:33.934  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
2016-04-27 11:01:33.938  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
2016-04-27 11:01:33.938  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: server: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
2016-04-27 11:01:33.938  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: server: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
2016-04-27 11:01:33.938  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
2016-04-27 11:01:33.938  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
2016-04-27 11:01:33.938  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: server: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
2016-04-27 11:01:33.938  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: server: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
2016-04-27 11:01:33.938  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
2016-04-27 11:01:33.938  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
2016-04-27 11:01:33.938  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: server: 
2016-04-27 11:01:33.938  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: server: 
2016-04-27 11:01:33.938  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: client: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
2016-04-27 11:01:33.938  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
2016-04-27 11:01:33.938  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
2016-04-27 11:01:33.938  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
2016-04-27 11:01:33.938  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
2016-04-27 11:01:33.938  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
2016-04-27 11:01:33.939  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: client: none
2016-04-27 11:01:33.939  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: client: none
2016-04-27 11:01:33.939  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: client: 
2016-04-27 11:01:33.939  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: client: 
2016-04-27 11:01:33.939  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
2016-04-27 11:01:33.939  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
2016-04-27 11:01:33.941  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
2016-04-27 11:01:33.941  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
2016-04-27 11:01:33.954  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
2016-04-27 11:01:33.954  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Host '<<Server_IP>>' is known and matches the RSA host key
2016-04-27 11:01:33.954  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
2016-04-27 11:01:33.954  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
2016-04-27 11:01:33.955  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
2016-04-27 11:01:33.960  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
2016-04-27 11:01:33.965  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
2016-04-27 11:01:33.966  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Next authentication method: publickey
2016-04-27 11:01:33.970  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Disconnecting from <<Server_IP>> port 22
2016-04-27 11:01:33.970 ERROR 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] c.s.l.s.s.i.SftpFileUploaderServiceImpl  : Exception occured while sending file:'Test_2016-04-27_2016-04-26_Test.tsv.tmp' to the SFTP server.
```

The more high level error looks like below::

```
<30>2016-04-27T02:55:05+02:00 docker-1.mscgn.de docker/smile-report-uploader[1098]: 
2016-04-27 00:55:05.528 ERROR 1 --- [sk-scheduler-10] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: ; nested exception is
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to obtain pooled item; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session 
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.wrapExceptionIfNecessary(AbstractDispatcher.java:133) 
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:120) 
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101) 
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97) 
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) 
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:286) 
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:245) 
    at com.sapient.lufthansa.smilereportuploader.service.impl.SftpFileUploaderServiceImpl.uploadFileToSftpServer(SftpFileUploaderServiceImpl.java:56) 
    at com.sapient.lufthansa.smilereportuploader.service.impl.FileUploaderHandlerImpl.startUploadingProcess(FileUploaderHandlerImpl.java:94) 
    at com.sapient.lufthansa.smilereportuploader.service.impl.FileUploaderHandlerImpl.handleUploadingRequest(FileUploaderHandlerImpl.java:76) 
    at com.sapient.lufthansa.smilereportuploader.scheduler.UploadingScheduler.startUploading(UploadingScheduler.java:48) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) 
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) 
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) 
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) 
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to obtain pooled item; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:178) 
    at  org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory.getSession(CachingSessionFactory.java:118) 
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:334) 
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:211) 
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:201) 
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:193) 
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(FileTransferringMessageHandler.java:110) 
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78) 
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) 
    ... 23 more 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session 
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:355) 
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:49) 
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:76) 
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:73) 
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.doGetItem(SimplePool.java:188) 
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:169) 
    ... 31 more 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:272) 
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:350) 
    ... 36 more 
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: session is down 
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.sendChannelOpen(Channel.java:762) 
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:151) 
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:145) 
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:267) 
    ... 37 more
```

What am i doing wrong? It has kept me stuck for few days now. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2016-04-27 11:01:33.966  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Next authentication method: publickey
>
> 2016-04-27 11:01:33.970  INFO 9460 --- [nio-9056-exec-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Disconnecting from <> port 22

Most likely a problem with the key or passphrase - look in the server logs.